# Function to import table data if not exist

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I am trying to make this function, which executes a .sql file exported from the database. The basic role of this function is to import table data if the desired table is empty. I have already made a function which checks if the table is empty, but cant get this one running. So far I am come up with this ..

```
function importdata($file) {

global $wpdb;
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

// Name of the file
$plugindir = dirname( __FILE__ );
$filename =  $plugindir . '/metaboxes/database/' . $file;

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);

// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
// Skip it if it's a comment
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
continue;

// Add this line to the current segment
$templine .= $line;



// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    // Perform the query
    $wpdb->query('$line');

    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
    echo "if is running";
    }
 }
}
```

I have added an echo in the if condition to check if it is reaching the condition. Apparently, it is reaching the if condition but not adding the rows ..

Comment: Which `if` condition? Plus, where's the part about "adding the rows"? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: `if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')`

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay let me see

Comment: @Fred-ii- It trigered various other warnings, but nothing displayed  where I used the function. It only says "if is runningif is runningif is runningif is runningif is runningif is running "

Comment: Seems like it's caught in an endless loop. I would tend to those other errors too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Let me see how many ';' can I find in the .sql file. If it matches the number of 'if is running' then its not the loop probably? Right?

Comment: It could be anything, have a look and see, but there's definitely an ongoing loop happening, by the looks of it.

Comment: There are exactly 6 ';' in the sql file. So that's probably fine, I think the issue is somewhere else ..

Comment: That's great Fahad, am glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the one's who need an answer for this, the problem was in wpdb->query. All I did to solve the issue was replaced $line with $templine. The problem was occurred because $line was only getting the lines with ';' in the file while the other data was stored in $templine. The final function which was running is ..

```
function importdata($file) {

global $wpdb;
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

// Name of the file
$plugindir = dirname( __FILE__ );
$filename =  $plugindir . '/metaboxes/database/' . $file;

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);

// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
// Skip it if it's a comment
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
continue;

// Add this line to the current segment
$templine .= $line;



// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    // Perform the query
    $wpdb->query($templine);
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
    echo "if is running";
    }
 }
}
```